# ValueError: Unknown label type sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I 'm new in sklearn. I 'm trying to do this code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['review'], df['nota'], random_state = 0)
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
```

And I saw this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([5. , 4. , 4. , 5. , 1.5, 3. , 4. , 1.9, 4.5, 4.5, 2.3, 1.5, 5. ,4.5, 4.3, 2.5, 1.5, 2.7, 4.5, 4. , 3.4, 3.5, 2. , 4. , 1.5, 4.8 ]),)
```

In column review there are phrases and in nota floats.

Answer (score 0):

i think its reading both type as objects why dont you try with following code.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x=df['review'],y=df['nota'].astype('float'), random_state = 0)
```